# OCR implementation using tesseract.js in ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic3, tesseract.js

I want to implement OCR in ionic 3 using tesseract.js. My code works fine when testing on the browser, however, when I run the app on my android device, it shows a blank page. Any idea will be of great importance. 
Here is a sample of my code:

```
import * as Tesseract from 'tesseract.js'; 

Tesseract.recognize("./img/img.jpg")<br>
    .progress((progress) => {<br>
    this.loader.present();<br>
    })<br>
    .then((tesseractResult) => {<br>
      this.loader.dismiss();<br>
      this.recognizedText = tesseractResult.text;<br>
      console.log("this is the data we collected from image");<br>
      this.alerts(this.recognizedText);<br>
    });
```

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: I actually found out that the code runs on other  android devices and for some it prevents the app from loading the root page. Now the issue turns to be why the discrimination in the device to execute on.